# Programmatically check a checkbox in pysimplegui

Tags: python, python-3.x, checkbox, pysimplegui, python-3.11

I have a PySimpleGUI application and I need to check a checkbox programmatically. I have looked at the cookbook, but couldn't find anything useful to help me. I have tried:

```py
window["-CHECKBOX-"].update(checked=True)
```

```py
window["-CHECKBOX-"}.update(default=True)
```

but both my attempts have given me a TypeError, saying that the update received an unexpected keyword argument.
I have no idea if this is possible in PySimpleGUI, it is a possibility that it simply is not possible. I am using the Tkinter port, so I could use the underlying tkinter module if need be. Thanks in advance! Note: I am using Python 3.11

Full relevant code:

```py
import pySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [
    [sg.Button("Check Checkbox", key="-CHECK-", enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Checkbox("Check me!", key="-CHECKBOX-", enable_events=True)]
]
window = sg.Window("Application", margins=(40,40), layout=layout, finalize=True, resizable=True) 

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "-CHECK-":
        pass # This would be where the code to check the checkbox would be
window.close()
```

Comment: The state of the checkbox is in `values["-CHECK-"]`.

Comment: Good catch! I just typed the code into the browser without testing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option for `checked` or `default` in method `update`. It should be

- `window["-CHECKBOX-"].update(value=True)`, or
- `window["-CHECKBOX-"].update(True)`.

You can find it in https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/call%20reference/#checkbox-element

> #### Checkbox.update
>
> Changes some of the settings for the Checkbox Element. Must call Window.Read or Window.Finalize prior. Note that changing visibility may cause element to change locations when made visible after invisible
>
> Changes will not be visible in your window until you call window.read or window.refresh.
>
> If you change visibility, your element may MOVE. If you want it to remain stationary, use the "layout helper" function "pin" to ensure your element is "pinned" to that location in your layout so that it returns there when made visible.

```py
update(value = None,
    text = None,
    background_color = None,
    text_color = None,
    checkbox_color = None,
    disabled = None,
    visible = None)
```

Parameter Descriptions:

| Type | Name | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **bool** | **value** | **if True checks the checkbox, False clears it** |
| str | text | Text to display next to checkbox |
| str | background_color | color of background |
| str | text_color | color of the text. Note this also changes the color of the checkmark |
| bool | disabled | disable or enable element |
| bool | visible | control visibility of element |

Comment: Thanks! Guess I just missed that in the cookbook